# How to sync MS SQL Server of Azure Portal with WordPress Database?

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I want to establish 2 way sync between MS SQL Database with WordPress Mysql Database. I even tried to use Workbench or Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL. But nothing worked. Every time i get some "Connection to MySQL Failed" Error.

I  have even tried all option i have seen online but noting worked.

Comment: What options have you tried?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server on prem or Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Bi-directoinal sync is impossible, you have to choose one of the two ways

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell us more about what you are trying to do.

As far as I can tell yo have 2 options:

1. Use [PolyBase](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mysql-odbc-polybase.rst#:%7E:text=PolyBase%20for%20SQL%20Server%20allows,alongside%20your%20SQL%20Server%20data.): Which is very impractical, close to retirement, lacking in documentation, and personally I wasn't able to install it not even once.
2. Use [Linked Servers](https://superuser.com/questions/163610/anyway-to-use-ssms-to-connect-to-mysql): As I posted in the reply you can follow the step by step guide and create a linked server to MySQL. From there you can query the linked server and eventually create a stored procedure that import/export data but forget about an on-time sync
3. Azure Data Factory: If you are on Azure SQL Database you can setup Azure Data Factory and create a pipeline for sync data. Or eventually use SSIS if you are on prem.